# Merge Sort algorithm Doesn't work(c++), facing problem getting no sense out of output

Tags: c++, recursion, merge, mergesort

I was solving a problem and i was using the same recursive method as used in merge sort. But it didn't give the desired output so i decided to implement basic merge sort first, and i think i am missing something in my recursive algo

**This is my merge sort, though i doubt there's anything wrong here but still if you need it for reference:**

```
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)  
{
    if (l < r)    
    {        
        int m = l+(r-l)/2;            
        // Sort first and second halves    
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);    
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);    
        // merge both the sorted array    
        merge(arr, l, m, r);    
    }    
}
```

**Now the merge function which i believe is incomplete or incorrect:**

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
     //these are going to be the iterators for our left, right and our final output array respectively
     int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
     // n1 is the size of the first array which is going to be one more than the differene of the mid index number and the first indexing number of the complete array
     int n1 = m - l + 1;
     // n2 is the size of the second array and the index of this array is starting from m + 1th element of the complete array
     int n2 = r - m;
     int L[n1];
     int R[n2];
     // populate the left array with elements upto n1 - 1th element of the array
     for (int x = 0; x < n1; x++)
     {
        L[x] = arr[x];
     }
     //populate the right array
     for (int x = 0; x < n2; x++)
     {
         R[x] = arr[x + n1];
     }
     while (i < n1 && j < n2)
     {
         if (L[i] <= R[j])
         {
             arr[k] = L[i];
             i++;
             k++;
         }
         else
         {
             arr[k] = R[j];
             j++;
             k++;
         }
     }
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I assume the `L` and `R` array declarations are pseudocode? You cannot declare arrays that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have some bug in your code.

1. you should take element starting from lower index in **merge** function, in left halve:

   L[x] = arr[l+x];
2. you need to it same for right halve too:

   R[x] = arr[m+x +1];
3. you should complete scanning in case of different length of array, when they are comparing in **merge** function:

   while(i < n1){
   arr[k++] = L[i++];
   }

   while(j <n2){
   arr[k++] = R[j++];
   }
4. and least but not the last, you should fill the array from the lower index, not always from 0:

   int i = 0, j = 0, k = l;

Here is final code, after modifying:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r){

 int i = 0, j = 0, k = l;
 int n1 = m - l + 1;

 int n2 = r - m;
 int L[n1];
 int R[n2];

 for (int x = 0; x < n1; x++)
 {
    L[x] = arr[l+x];
 }

 for (int x = 0; x < n2; x++)
 {
     R[x] = arr[m+x +1];
 }
 while (i < n1 && j < n2)
 {
     if (L[i] <= R[j])
     {
         arr[k] = L[i];
         i++;
         k++;
     }
     else
     {
         arr[k] = R[j];
         j++;
         k++;
     }
 }
 
 while(i < n1){
     arr[k++] = L[i++];
 }
 
 while(j <n2){
     arr[k++] = R[j++];
 }
}

 void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)  {
  if (l < r){        
    int m = l+(r-l)/2;            

    mergeSort(arr, l, m);    
    mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);    

    merge(arr, l, m, r);    
  }    
}

void main(){
  int arr[4] ={3, 1, 2, 5};
  mergeSort(arr, 0, 3);

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
     printf("%i ", arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is my first recursion algo implmentation so it took me a while to understand it, but it worked. Thnk you so much for your help